# How to find minimum element in an array repeatedly but between different indices input by user.

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

An array of n numbers is given. Number of times minimum to be found out is given,let it be p, Indices are also given for each case repeatedly . I traversed the array to find min in array between given indices and repeated this procedure p times using for loop but I want it to be more efficient, How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need, is to use some efficient algorithm for [Range Minimum Query](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/) problem. Please follow the provided link. There you will find a comprehensive explanation how to do this.

Comment: Interesting stuff ... but that's for the online case, where the ranges aren't known in advance. It seems in OPs case the ranges are known in advance, so much simpler solution is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the number of queries, the kind of queries etc.

Without any such information, taking an O(n) time pre-processing hit for Range Minimum Query setup will make each of the min queries O(1).

Depending on the expected query patterns etc, there are tradeoffs that you can make.

Comment: In case of expected query pattern how can it be more efficient?

Comment: Those are nice bounds, but they aren't realized by any of the algorithms on the page you are referencing. -1.